# Como eu configuro o HHVM para um apache compilado manualmente?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hhvm

Durante as atualizações do **Ubuntu 12.04**, o **HHVM** foi atualizado e então foi solicitado para que eu executasse o comando de instalação do **fast_cgi**.

Porém ao executar recebi o seguinte erro:

```
➜  ~  sudo /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh 
Checking if Apache is installed
WARNING: Couldn't find Apache2 configuration paths, not configuring
Checking if Nginx is installed
Nginx not found
```

Isso ocorreu porque o meu Apache foi compilado manualmente e instalado em um diretório diferente: `/etc/apache247/`.

Como eu configuro o instalador do **fast_cgi** para encontrar essa instalação?

Segue parte do script abaixo, para um melhor compreendimento ([script completo](https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/9845913)):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /etc/init.d/hhvm ]
then
        /etc/init.d/hhvm start
fi

#!/bin/bash

apache_check_installed() {
        echo "Checking if Apache is installed"
        if [ \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-enabled \) -o \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-available \) ]
        then
                echo "WARNING: Couldn't find Apache2 configuration paths, not configuring"
                return 1
        fi
        echo "Detected Apache installation"
        return 0
}
```

---

### Ubuntu 14.04 [EDIT]

Recentemente atualizei o Ubuntu para a versão 14.04, e instalei o Apache/PHP usando repositórios atualizados, com isso utilizei o `apt-get` mesmo.

Dessa forma o HHVM funcionou tranquilamente.

Porém o motivo dessa questão na época era: **como utilizar o HHVM com o apache compilado manualmente, pois não há a pasta mods-enabled, entre outras.. a estrutura é diferente.**

---

**Se alguém der down vote**, *por favor explique o motivo, para que eu "corrija isso". Afinal de contas: eu não tenho bola de cristal.*

Answer (score 2):

Segue um passo a passo prático:

1. Instale o HHVM

   ```
   echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu saucy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install hhvm-fastcgi
   ```
2. Instale o Apache2

   ```
   apt-get install apache2
   a2enmod proxy
   a2enmd proxy_fcgi
   ```
3. Instale o FastCGI

   ```
   apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
   a2enmod fastcgi
   update-rc.d hhvm-fastcgi defaults
   ```

Comment: A única maneira é com o apache instalado através do `apt-get`?  De qualquer forma, logo após esse post e assim que liberou a versão 14.04 eu instalei o apache através de um repositório mais recente utilizando o `apt-get` e funcionou. Mas minha dúvida era **em relação a instalação do HHVM utilizando o apache complicado manualmente em uma pasta alternativa**. Anyway, obrigado.

Comment: fui pelo mais pratico, embora sabia o que vc precisava porém não encontrei nenhuma documentação sobre sua dúvida

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir esta linha:

```
if [ \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-enabled \) -o \( ! -d /etc/apache2/mods-available \) ]
```

Por esta:

```
if [ \( ! -d /etc/apache247/mods-enabled \) -o \( ! -d /etc/apache247/mods-available \) ]
```

O script não está encontrando o caminho porque você compilou manualmente e instalou em outro local. Alterando o local no script deve solucionar seu problema.